# Load Preferences null value

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sharedpreferences

```
private void SavePreferences(){
    try
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        myScore = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.score)).getText().toString();
        myWord = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.word)).getText().toString();
        editor.putString("saveScore", myScore.toString());
        editor.putString("saveWord", myWord.toString());
        editor.commit();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("scoreText or wordView are null " + e.getMessage());
    }

}    

private void LoadPreferences(){
    try {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        myScore = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.score)).getText().toString();
        myWord = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.word)).getText().toString();
        scoreText.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("saveScore", myScore.toString()));
        wordView.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("saveWord", myWord.toString()));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("scoreText or wordView are null " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

scoretext and wordView are not being assgned the values from myScore and myWord, all though when debugged they have a value.

Debug result:

```
myScore:"990" scoreText :null
wordView: null myWord"_ _ a _ _"
```

EDIT:

Where the savePrefernces is called:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    SavePreferences();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Where Load Preferences is called:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_avtivity);
    LoadPreferences();
}
```

The loadPrefernces was called in the onBackPressed to check if myScore or myWord where null.

When load preferences is called from the onCreate the exception is being called!

Error Message:

The message is called the first time where the value are still null(exception was expected) and also the second time when the value should not be null(exception was not expected)

> 05-13 17:23:06.671 31547-31547/mt.edu.mcast.guesstheword2
>   W/System.err: scoreText or wordView are null Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)'
>   on a null object reference

Comment: Is your loadPreferences and savePreferences function called from the same activity?

Comment: To be able to debug I made both methods onBackPressed.(To check if myScore and myWord had a value). Loadprefernces should be implemented onCreate ,but  when inserted into the onCreate it's getting into the exception (scoreText or wordView are null).

Comment: Call from the same onBackPressed function? Can you show the function code?

Comment: In `onCreate()` you are loading prefs which you have not saved it yet because you are saving those in `onBackPressed()`. You will definitely get exception.

Comment: ofc i will get an exception the first time I go into the activity but on the second time(when i backPress and then i open the activity again) it should  load those preferences.

Comment: where have you initialized scoreText and  wordView TextView...please initialize them by giving them reference. Since your scoreText is null hence when you try scoreText.setView...it is giving null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  private void LoadPreferences(){
        try {
            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
            initailizeView();
            scoreText.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("saveScore", "default"));
            wordView.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("saveWord","default"));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("scoreText or wordView are null " + e.getMessage());
        }
}
```

sharedPreferences.getString has two parameters the "key" and "defValue". By re assigning the value in the "defValue" I would  also get a null value as my variable was null. The value had to be retrieved from the first parameters "key" as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

"`getPreferences`" has a private access to activity. if you use "`LoadPreferences()`" from another activity use "`getSharedPreferences`"

**Sample:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("YourApp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Comment: The LoadPrefernces is called in the same activity, after the user presses the back press and the re enters the activity.

Comment: You invoke '"LoadPreferences()' in OnCreate method. When user press back button activity is still exists. After user re enters, OnCreate doesnt invoke. And why you used 'SavePreferences()' in onBackPressed? User can roll up you activity without press back button. Maybe onDestroy is better

Comment: So i Changed the savePrefernces to be called onDestroy and the Loadprefernces to be called onStart. The problem is that myScore and myWord are null when being called in on LoadPrefernces but they are not null when being saved on savePrefernces.

Answer (score 0):

Change your onCreate as below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_avtivity);
    initailizeView();
    LoadPreferences();
}

protected void initailizeView() {
    scoreText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score)
    wordView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.word)
}
```

> Here I have assumed that R.id.score and R.id.word are two textViews.

Comment: Still it doesn't work. I did the re assign the values in loadRefernces as shown above. Can it be that the AVD is buggy?